# Should I make any changes in the following code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not able to find any problem in these code. Could you please help me to fix it.

```
e_type = int(input(
'''ENTER EMPLOYEE TYPE
    [1] PERSONAL BANKER
    [2] TELLER
    [3] MANAGER'''))
    while True:
        if e_type == 1:
            e_type = '_personal_banker_'
            break
        elif e_type == 2:
            e_type = '_teller_'
            break
        elif e_type == 3:
            e_type = '_manager_'
            break
        else:
            print('INVALID ENTRY! TRY AGAIN...')
            e_type = int(input(
'''ENTER EMPLOYEE TYPE
    [1] PERSONAL BANKER
    [2] TELLER
    [3] MANAGER'''))
```

Answer (score 0):

`While True` should not be indented.

```
e_type = int(input(
'''ENTER EMPLOYEE TYPE
    [1] PERSONAL BANKER
    [2] TELLER
    [3] MANAGER'''))
while True:
    if e_type == 1:
        e_type = '_personal_banker_'
        break
    elif e_type == 2:
        e_type = '_teller_'
        break
    elif e_type == 3:
        e_type = '_manager_'
        break
    else:
        print('INVALID ENTRY! TRY AGAIN...')
```

However, if you wish the question to be repeated until a proper answer is given, then just move the input into the while loop.

```
while True:
    e_type = int(input(
    '''ENTER EMPLOYEE TYPE
        [1] PERSONAL BANKER
        [2] TELLER
        [3] MANAGER'''))
    if e_type == 1:
        e_type = '_personal_banker_'
        break
    elif e_type == 2:
        e_type = '_teller_'
        break
    elif e_type == 3:
        e_type = '_manager_'
        break
    else:
        print('INVALID ENTRY! TRY AGAIN...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Structure your program a litter better. The return type of the `input` function is a `str`. Try not to use `while True`.

```
prompt = '''ENTER EMPLOYEE TYPE
    [1] PERSONAL BANKER
    [2] TELLER
    [3] MANAGER
    '''

ans = ''
while ans not in ['1', '2', '3']:
    ans = input(prompt)
    if ans == '1':
        e_type = '_personal_banker_'
    elif ans == '2':
        e_type = '_teller_'
    elif ans == '3':
        e_type = '_manager_'
    else:
        print('INVALID ENTRY! TRY AGAIN...')
```